# Dynamic list in dropdown menu

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu

I want to drop down a menu on link click, I have searched and found all the dropdown menus are static list, but i want to make the list dynamically on link click, something like a function called to fill the list of the dropdown menu when clicking on the link.
What i have found is:

```
<li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span>Products</span></a>
  <ul>
     <li><a href='#'><span>Product 1</span></a></li>
     <li><a href='#'><span>Product 2</span></a></li>
     <li class='last'><a href='#'><span>Product 3</span></a></li>
  </ul>
```

but i want to replace the inner list, which are in the above code (Product1, Product2, Product3) with dynamic list.

I am making the following list

```
document.getElementById("listPaths").innerHTML += "<ul style='list-style-type:circle;color: white' class='cl-effect-1'><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><li>" + "<a href='#' style='text-decoration: none;' onclick=" + "'getRoutesList(" + countList + ");'>" + "Path " + countList + "</a>" + "</li></ul>";
```

and i want to make a function that fills a menu list when link is clicked.I can't insert an inner list inside my listPaths using innerHTML.

Comment: so what is your question? what problem are u having?

Comment: where is the element with id 'listPaths'?

Comment: It is a div. Here it is: `<div style="float: left; width:24%; height:50%; " id="listPaths"></div>`

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working sample:

http://jsfiddle.net/q1hrf314/

```
<input type="button" onclick="updateList()" value="Update List"/>

<ul>
    <li id="listPaths">
        <ul>
     <li><a href='#'><span>Product 1</span></a></li>
     <li><a href='#'><span>Product 2</span></a></li>
     <li class='last'><a href='#'><span>Product 3</span></a></li>
  </ul>
    </li>
</ul>


var countList = 1;
function getRoutesList(countList) {
    alert('countList = ' + countList);
}

function updateList(){
document.getElementById("listPaths").innerHTML += "<ul style='list-style-type:circle;color: white' class='cl-effect-1'><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><li>" + "<a href='#' style='text-decoration: none;' onclick=" + "'getRoutesList(" + countList + ");'>" + "Path " + countList + "</a>" + "</li></ul>";
}
```

Comment: But when i click on the link, no div appears.